# Нестандартные элементы

Tags: wpf

Как создаются подобные элементы ?

- Особенно если их необходимо воссоздавать (отображать) программно.

Достаточно просто ссылок, понятия не имею на какой запрос подобное гуглить.

Нашёл только то, что можно в `Border` поместить `TextBlock` и закруглить углы у `Border`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или просто создать 2 `Border`, а у них внутри `TextBlock`, задать слои и 1 смещать относительно другого ?

Comment: Это же штатный GroupBox, просто стилизуйте его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начните с этого:

```
<GroupBox Header="Text 1">
    <TextBlock Text="Text 2"/>
</GroupBox>
```

Затем, ПКМ по `GroupBox` в дизайнере и <kbd>Edit Template</kbd>><kbd>Edit a Copy...</kbd>, вводите имя для стиля и нажмите <kbd>OK</kbd>, у меня добавился такой стиль:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                            <Border.OpacityMask>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7" Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Border.OpacityMask>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Правим:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="MyGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                            <Border.OpacityMask>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="20" Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Border.OpacityMask>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Header" Background="Black" CornerRadius="8" Grid.Column="1" Padding="15,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="5">
    <GroupBox Style="{DynamicResource MyGroupBoxStyle}">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Text 1" FontSize="16" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="White"/>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Text 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. Показан в предыдущем примере, когда вы создаете Стиль (`Style`) меняющий отображение элемента управления за счет переопределения Шаблона (`Template`). Подробнее про это можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating). Там на раздел про шаблоны элементов управления обратите внимание.
2. Вы можете создать пользовательский элемент управления (`UserControl`) у которого будет как у формы файл XAML и файл с кодом на C#. И в дальнейшем его использовать как и обычные контролы поставляемые в WPF. Подробнее про это можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Для начала проще использовать второй вариант.

1. Создаете пустой WPF проект
2. Правый клик на проекте Add → User Control
3. В открывшемся окне задаете его имя. Я не менял.
4. Определяете что у вас будет в рамках вашего контрола, я задал ширину и высоту, плюс добавил красный эллипс. У вас может быть любая комбинация контролов, которая необходима вам для решения задачи.
   Вот так выглядит XAML:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfApp4.UserControl1"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
                    mc:Ignorable="d" 
                    Width="40" Height="40">
       <Grid>
           <Ellipse Fill="Red" />
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```
5. Вот так будет выглядеть XAML главной формы:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
       <Grid x:Name="grMain">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
6. Ну и в коде главной формы прописываем следующий код:

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
       }

       private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
           {
               UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
               Grid.SetRow(control, i);
               grMain.Children.Add(control);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Вот так это выглядит после запуска программы.

[image: результат запуска]

Comment: Сниппеты кода предназначены для запуска HTML/CSS/JS, и не для чего другого, используйте просто 4 отступа, которые можно вставить другой кнопкой в редакторе сайта.