# Как задать стиль ScrollViewer встроенного в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

В TreeView есть готовый ScrollViewer. Как задать стиль для этого ScrollViewer ?

---

Нашел на msdn некоторые статьи, но как совместить это все не представляю 
для TreeView (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates) для ScrollViewer (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-styles-and-templates)

---

В КАКОМ МЕСТЕ ЭТО ДУБЛИКАТ !?!? [Нестандартные элементы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883728/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: Применить стиль приложению, т.е. переопределить его. `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}", BasedOn={StarticResource someStyle} />`

Comment: Не понимаю. У меня есть стиль для TreeView , есть стиль для ScrollViewer. И как переопределить стиль ScrollViewer в TreeView ?

Comment: Смотрите тот топик: *Затем, ПКМ по GroupBox в дизайнере и Edit Template>Edit a Copy..., вводите имя для стиля и нажмите OK, у меня добавился такой стиль:* вот вам нужно сделать абсолютно то же самое с TreeView и в шаблоне найти ScrollViewer и установить ему нужный стиль. Другого решения нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.